# pymssql cannot retrieve data on ubuntu 12

Tags: ubuntu, pymssql

pymssql module cannot retrieve result on Ubuntu 12.04, what can I do?

Ubuntu 11.10 (GNU/Linux 3.0.0-30-generic-pae i686):

```
tim@lbtim:~$ python
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Jul 20 2012, 22:12:53)
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pymssql
>>> conn = pymssql.connect(host='10.156.70.7')
>>> curr = conn.cursor()
>>> curr.execute("select name from sysobjects where type='u'")
>>> for tbname, in curr:
...     print tbname
...
spt_fallback_db
spt_fallback_dev
spt_fallback_usg
spt_monitor
spt_values
MSreplication_options
bo_aux_callmeet_registed
>>> curr.close()
>>> conn.close()
>>> exit()
tim@lbtim:~$
```

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae i686):

```
tim@lbtim:~$ python
Python 2.7.3+ (default, Apr 20 2012, 22:44:07)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pymssql
>>> conn = pymssql.connect(host='10.156.70.7')
>>> curr = conn.cursor()
>>> curr.execute("select name from sysobjects where type='u'")
>>> for tbname, in curr:
...     print tbname
...
>>> curr.close()
>>> conn.close()
>>> exit()
tim@lbtim:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm with that too, but seems to be a compatibility issue with FreeTDS and pymssql in ubuntu 12.04.

see here.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pymssql/+bug/918896